# JavaScript Remove upper Element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to remove the whole `<div class="form-group">` when I click on the `<span type="button">`.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input required="" placeholder="Voeg een highlight toe" class="form-control" name="highlight[]" type="text">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <span onclick="removeRow(this)" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                    Verwijder
                </span>                 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It must be look like this:

```
<script>
    function removeRow(element){
        element.parentNode.remove();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So what problem are you facing?

Comment: When the function runs, he remove nothing visibles..

Comment: Try `element.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(element.parentNode);`

Comment: `I want to remove the whole <div class="form-group"> `: wait a min... you need to traverse the tree up, to reach required element. reach to its parent & remove that parent's child. (Refer my earlier comment for reference)

Comment: @anishsane It works half, he only removes the `<span type="button">`

Comment: @anishsane yes, that is want I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just traverse the tree up to that node and remove it.

```
function removeRow(element){
    element.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ScAKL/2/)

Comment: `parent.parent.parent...` is bad because you are tightly coupling it to the html structure. If he wants to change that HTML he has to make sure he adds or removes one more `parentNode`.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this

```
<div class="form-group" id="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input required="" placeholder="Voeg een highlight toe" class="form-control" name="highlight[]" type="text">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-default" id="clickme" type="button">
                Verwijder
            </span>                 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Then the js

```
var cm = document.getElementById('clickme');
cm.addEventListener('click',function(){
  console.log('clicked');
  var fg = document.getElementById('form-group');
  fg.parentElement.removeChild(fg);
});
```

see fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/X8Cwq/